# How can I make a table that contains other tags

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to make a table that contains HTML tags, but when I enter an HTML tag it is recognized and it does not appear.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><html></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A html tag can only be present once in a HTML document. But you can insert other tags.

Comment: An HTML document can only contain one, root level `html` element. What you are trying to do is invalid HTML. Can you please explain what _exactly_ you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Escape sequences!! do ur homework on google!

Comment: Use `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of `<` and `>`.

Comment: Please Clarify what you are asking.  are you thinking of Iframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the HTML tags that are allowed to be placed within the body-element of an HTML-page can be placed within a TD as well, but you cannot have more than one HTML-element in the page.

For example, this would be allowed:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <table border="1">
              <tr>
                 <td>Some content</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, if you want to show the text <HTML> in your table, then you would have to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`, like this `&lt;HTML&gt;` otherwise the browser would try to parse it as HTML instead of printing it as text.